# C language - record data (add,delete) in text file using file IO, structure, function, array, pointers

Tags: c, file-io, text-files

I'm still learning intro to C language. Currently I'm having problem with my code. The task is to ask user to input information about staff and write them into a text file. The problem occur when:

1) output in text/.exe file display random characters.

2) a new output will overwrite the existing information in the text/.exe file

3) the delete function unable to delete correctly after the first time i delete a staff information in text file.

I would be so happy if I can solve any of these 3 problem :)

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Menu();
void New_Staff();
void Delete_Staff();
void Export_Profile();

struct element{
    char id[20];
    char name[20];
    char gender[20];
    char phone[20];
    char email[20];
}profile;

int main(void){      //The program will continue running until option 4 selected                                   
    int a;  

    for(a=0;;a++){
       Menu();
    }
    return 0;
}

void Menu()      //Main Menu to select option
{
    int n;
    printf("\n**********************************************");
    printf("\nMAIN MENU-STAFF INFORMATION SYSTEM");
    printf("\n**********************************************");
    printf("\n1. Add profile Staff Profile");
    printf("\n2. Delete Staff Profile");
    printf("\n3. Export All Profiles to 'output.txt'");
    printf("\n4. Exit");
    printf("\n**********************************************");
    printf("\nPlease enter your option< 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 >: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    switch(n){
    case 1:
        New_Staff();
        break;
    case 2:
        Delete_Staff();
        break;
    case 3:
        Export_Profile();
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("\n*** Thanks for using the program! Goodbye. ***");
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nError! Wrong Number is Entered\nPlease Try Again");
        break;
    }
}

void New_Staff()                        //Add New Staff Profile 
{   
    int x;
    struct element profile;

    printf("\n===Add New Staff Profile===");
    printf("\n\nPlease enter the following staff information.");

    printf("\n\nStaff ID: ");
    scanf("%s", &profile.id);

    printf("Name\t: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(profile.name,20,stdin);

    for(x=0 ; x<20 ; x++)
    {
    if(profile.name[x] == '\n')
        profile.name[x] = '\0';
    }

    printf("Gender\t: ");
    scanf("%s", &profile.gender);

    printf("Phone\t: ");
    scanf("%s", &profile.phone);

    printf("Email\t: ");
    scanf("%s", &profile.email);

    printf("\nSYSTEM: New Staff Profile is Added Successfully.");

}

void Delete_Staff()         //Delete Staff Profile
{                   
    FILE *fRead, *fWrite;
    char *TextFile;
    char c;
    int Delete_Id, temp = 1;

    TextFile="output.txt";

    fRead = fopen(TextFile, "r");
    c = getc(fRead);

    while (c != EOF){
    printf("%c", c);
    c = getc(fRead); 
    }

    rewind(fRead);

    printf("\nDelete Staff with ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &Delete_Id);

    Delete_Id=Delete_Id+1;

    fWrite = fopen("copy.c", "w");
    c = getc(fRead);
    while (c != EOF) {
    c = getc(fRead);
    if (c == '\n')
    temp++;
    if (temp != Delete_Id){
    putc(c, fWrite); 
       } 
    }

    fclose(fRead);
    fclose(fWrite);

    remove(TextFile);

    rename("copy.c", TextFile);
    printf("\nThe contents of file after being modified are as follows:\n");

    fRead = fopen(TextFile, "r");
    c = getc(fRead);
    while (c != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
    c = getc(fRead);
    }

    fclose(fRead);
}

void Export_Profile()           //Export Staff Profile to Text
{       
    struct element profile;

    FILE *fPtr;
    fPtr=fopen("output.txt","w");
    FILE *fPtr1;
    fPtr1=fopen("output.txt","a+");

    if (fPtr == NULL)
    printf("Error in opening file\n");
    if (fPtr1 == NULL)
    printf("Error in opening file\n");

    fprintf(fPtr,"%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s","Staff","ID",
             "Name","Gender","Phone","Email");

    fprintf(fPtr1,"\n%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s", profile.id, profile.name,   
             profile.gender, profile.phone, profile.email);

    printf("\n%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s", "Staff", "ID", "Name",
             "Gender", "Phone",  "Email");
    printf("\n%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s", profile.id, 
             profile.name, profile.gender, profile.phone, profile.email);

    printf("\nSYSTEM: All staff profile have been exported to output.txt file");

    fclose(fPtr);
    fclose(fPtr1);
}
```

I'm sorry for the long code. I not really sure where problem lies.

The output give this:

```
**********************************************
MAIN MENU-STAFF INFORMATION SYSTEM
**********************************************
1. Add profile Staff Profile
2. Delete Staff Profile
3. Export All Profiles to 'output.txt'
4. Exit
**********************************************
Please enter your option< 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 >: 1

===Add New Staff Profile===

Please enter the following staff information.

Staff ID: 1
Name    : Carmen Gray
Gender  : Female
Phone   : 123-4567890
Email   : carmen@live.com

SYSTEM: New Staff Profile is Added Successfully.
**********************************************
MAIN MENU-STAFF INFORMATION SYSTEM
**********************************************
1. Add profile Staff Profile
2. Delete Staff Profile
3. Export All Profiles to 'output.txt'
4. Exit
**********************************************
Please enter your option< 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 >: 3

 Staff         ID       Name     Gender      Phone
   °²#                @Γg╕∙         ∙
SYSTEM: All staff profile have been exported to output.txt file
**********************************************
MAIN MENU-STAFF INFORMATION SYSTEM
**********************************************
1. Add profile Staff Profile
2. Delete Staff Profile
3. Export All Profiles to 'output.txt'
4. Exit
**********************************************
Please enter your option< 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 >: 2

 Staff         ID       Name     Gender      Phone
   °²#                @Γg╕∙        .

Delete Staff with ID: 1

The contents of file after being modified are as follows:
 Staff         ID       Name     Gender      Phone
```

and the text file display this:

```
   Staff         ID       Name     Gender      Phone
     øý#                @âg¸ù         ù
```

Comment: If you are Unix and Linux based system then `fflush(stdin);` is Undefined behavior you are using in `New_Staff()` function and its safe to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` for strings to avoid buffer overflow

Comment: What you try is to reinvent databases. So if you are not learning from this example, I'd recommend to use a database instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Export_Profile()` the `profile` variable is not set to appropriate value.

```
void Export_Profile()           //Export Staff Profile to Text
{       
    struct element profile; // this has not been set to actual value.
    ...
    fprintf(fPtr1,"\n%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s", profile.id, profile.name,   
         profile.gender, profile.phone, profile.email);
    ....
}
```

You may want to store data in some global variable or array of variables or linked list. Set them in `New_Profile()` and use them other functions like `Export_Profile()`.

Comment: +1 Furthermore, both `profile` in `New_Staff` and `Export_Profile` are local variables and have nothing to do with each other. `New_Staff` reads data and promptly loses it as soon as function scope exists.

Comment: how i can pass the data from the New_Staff into the Export_Profile?

Comment: @NabilFikri: As you have a global `struct element`, just comment out the two local declarations.

Comment: do you if you can give example on how to set the struct to actual value? i unable to get the clear picture yet.

Comment: @NabilFikri, as I updated in answer, you can use global variable instead of local variable.

Answer (score 2):

**3) the delete function unable to delete correctly after the first time i delete a staff information in text file.**

You are using a counter variable `temp` for the id, so suppose there are 10 ids from 1-10, now you delete 6.
Next time you call `Delete_Staff()`, you start with `temp=1`. Suppose you want to delete 7, the id 7 is now on the 6th line, but you delete the 7th line.
You should rather compare the `staff_id` from the file, with the id that you want to delete.
You can use the `atoi` function to convert the string to integer.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file in "w" mode causes the deletion of its previous content. Use "a", "a+" or "r+" if you want to write without erasing previous content.

Answer (score 0):

you should make use of "fread" and "fwrite" function for reading/writing a file. and all i/o is ideal to be done under binary mode, "rb+"/"wb+", fwrite and fread function deal with data more efficiently. I love making such menu driven programs :) . 
it's better to use "while(1)" indefinite loop instead of "(for(a=0;;a++)".